# Gnome task bar - No menus visible

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

Gnome doesn't display any of the icons on the top right hand side of the taskbar i.e. the messaging, network,system tools etc. Please help me with that. There's an image link.

Gnome:

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/nachiketjoshi/9617342697/]

Unity:

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/nachiketjoshi/9620578822/]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem with GNOME panel indicator applet. So, I suggest you to (re)install it. It's available in Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: indicator-applet]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried re-installing GNOME panel indicator applet, but that has not yet fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Gnome doesn't have the side menu, I am using Linux GNOME and don't have the side bar on my computer.

If you do want the side bar menu then probably use Unity. Either then that, It's probably a software problem as someone said above.

Comment: No, it did display for a few days and then all of a sudden it's gone. I'm not sure what happened.